# What's the best way to send data from user control to the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, user-controls

I have a page (A) and a user control and I want to send set of data like this:

> id  name
>
> 1   aa.pdf
>
> 2   bb.doc
>
> 3   cc.xls

---

from user control to my page

What 's the most effective way to do some thing like this ?

Comment: no i don't want to do this . my design require to send this list from user control to my page

Comment: Your design shouldn't _"require to send this list from user control to my page"_. That's wrong.

Comment: then what 's the right way to do this

Comment: Set the data in a hashtable and put in session

Comment: I would prefer exposing a public/internal property in a user control that page can use to get the data. Will use event from user control if the values are going to be available only after page load or values can change multiple times during page life cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a property on your `User Control` with the Datatype of the Data you want to pass to it, and populate it in your page on creation of the control.

```
public String ControlProperty
{
    get
    {
        return Convert.ToString(ViewState["ControlValue"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this. Usually, code is pust in a normal ASCX control, and then the control is just dragged onto the page. Putting data onto the page, indirectly :

Some of the most common are using .NET gridview, datagrid, or datalist. Binding a dataset, or datatable to the grid itself. This does not involve much work and you can follow many examples such as the following http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataBindingInDataGridMCB112022005002207AM/DataBindingInDataGridMCB1.aspx

Another way which involves more work is calling to a web service, which posts back a json object containing a list of rows, which you would iterate by client side scripting, and create an HTML table.

It is more a question of what your scenario is, and which is the best and most suitable way for you.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy, put your data into a Dictioary, and then save Dictionary into page context.

```
var myData = new Dictionary<int, String>();
myData[0]="aa.pdf";
context.Item["Data"] = myData;

//in your page.
var myData = (Dictionary<int, String>)(context.Item["Data"]);
```

above code is only prototype draft, you can try it in your environment.

Sean

Comment: It will be lost during Postback.